# asp.net mvc linq checking list for iqueyable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

1. I have a no. of records being inserted in a List<> .
2. I have IQueryable returning more then one record
3. I want to check whether the records IQueryable returns are present in the list or not?

is there any way in linq i can do that?

Comment: I will suggest you to add the IQueryable records in one IQueryable and then check if it contains the element

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Union of both list of records that u can use "Union()" of "Intersect()"(if you are interested in intersection), if you are talking about Left or Right joins on these lists, the you should look at 
[Left Join, Right Join Using LINQ](http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/left-join-right-join-using-linq/)

Hope this shall help.

Comment: No i am talking about checking the records in the list with the records coming from the query.

Comment: What is the resultant you want, matched records?? or unmatched records??